# Firebase Testlab showing error "Failed to load catalog"

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-test-lab

I want to test my app in **firebase test lab** but I am facing error **Failed to load catalog, Please try again in few minutes**

[image]

I followed all the steps which I have to follow [iOS Testlab Guidelines](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/ios/firebase-console?authuser=1#build_xctests_for_your_app)

After I uploaded the xctest.zip file I can't show any devices also.|

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you're having problems with an error in the Firebase console, contact Firebase support directly.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: You can also join the [Firebase Community](https://firebase.community/) Slack and join the #test-lab channel. The engineering team can take a closer look at your specific issue.

Comment: @Doug I know firebase support can help me out so I already contact them but normally it takes 1 or 2 days to replay and it's kind urgent so I came here.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a place to deal with [urgent issues](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest).  It's also for programming questions, which this is not.